# Is there any significance to Frankie Avalon's apperarance on Casino (1995)?

Tags: casino

When Robert De Niro's character launches a short-lived talk show in the movie Casino (1995), his first guest is singer Frankie Avalon in a cameo appearance. Why was this singer selected for this role? Did it have any special significance?

Comment: Not an answer, as I know of no "special significance" but as well as being a famous singer, he was also a reasonably accomplished actor & had in his later career performed in such as Grease & Happy Days. He was a safe bet.